# ¿Cómo puedo leer un csv desde la 5ta linea con php?

Tags: php, csv, fgets, fopen

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
if (($fichero = fopen("archivo.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($datos = fgetcsv($fichero, 1000)) !== FALSE) {
        echo $datos[0];
    }
}
```

El cual lee un archivo csv y muestra los datos que hay en cada columna según una cantidad indeterminada de filas.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que empiece a leer desde la 5ta fila?, ya que las 4 primeras son de solo encabezados?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede agregar un contador que aumente en cada ciclo while:

```
$row = 0;
while ($datos = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024)) {
    if (5 <= $row)
        echo  $datos[1] ."<br>";
    $row++;
```

}

Comment: ¡Gracias!, había pensado en la idea de agregar un contador pero no de la forma que propusiste tú.

Finalmente, el código quedó como lo aparece más abajo.

Answer (score 0):

Antes del `while` lee cuatro líneas:

```
$skip=4;
while($skip-->0)
  fgets($fichero);
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue como la propuso Igmer Rodríguez.

```
<?php 
if (($fichero = fopen("archivo.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $row = 0;
    while (($datos = fgetcsv($fichero, 1000)) !== FALSE) {
        if (4 <= $row){
        echo $datos[0];
        echo $datos[2];
        }        
        $row++;
    }
}
?>
```